# Cannot find module issue with imports-loader when testing with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest, imports-loader

When I am testing React components using Jest, I get following error for those components using imports-loader.

```
Cannot find module 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery!bootstrap/js/tooltip'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should install the missing module:

```
npm install imports-loader
```